# Is there anything to eat besides basic rations?

Tags: pixel-dungeon

In other roguelikes, I've been able to carve up corpses of fallen foes to eat when I'm hungry. In Pixel Dungeon, so far it looks like the only way to eat is to find a ration. It does take quite a long time to die to starvation, but you don't passively heal while you're starving, so it's still an inevitable death.

Is there anything else to eat besides rations? If not, what is the best way to manage hunger to deal with the seemingly insufficient supply?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Ring of Satiety (rare) can help prevent starvation. The Rogue class also suffers from hunger less than the Mage or Warrior. Likewise, the Warrior will regin a small amount of health when eating (which offsets the need to rest as often).

Otherwise, look for the dew drops that appear when walking through tall grass/mushroom/flower tiles. They will provide a small amount of HP.

An enchanted vampiric weapon will also regain some of your health when you strike with it.

The Mage's subclass: "Warlock" will have his hunger eased slightly, and wounds healed a little, with each enemy killed.

So, there are some ways. Also, it doesn't seem that Hunger causes any negative side effects, so I suggest you wait until you are Starving in order to ration out your food the most effectively. I usually wait until I am around 70% health before consuming the next ration, since being well-fed will replenish that health.

A well of healing will also remove hunger/starving status.

Also, while Mystery Meat will randomly cause a negative condition, you can burn it in fire trap or with Firebolt Wand to create "chargrilled steak" which has same nutritional value as previous, but without negative affect. This makes piranha's much more useful if they can be farmed safely (battle wands and boomerangs).

Comment: As a follow up, a Garden (being under the buff of Shadow or whatever) will make your hunger go up more slowly. This is a good place to rest without necessarily burning through your whole hunger cycle.

Comment: Also, while Mystery Meat will randomly cause a negative condition, you can burn it in fire trap or with firebolt wand to create "chargrilled steak" which has same nutritional value as previous, but without negative affect.

Comment: +1 great answer. You should edit your comments into your answer

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Wiki](http://pixeldungeon.wikia.com/wiki/Other_Items) there are other food items.

> **Ration of food**
>
> "Nothing fancy here: dried meat, some biscuits - things like that."
>
> This type of food is the most common in the game. Most of the levels have this food in one of their normal or special rooms. you start f the game with one ration of food
>
> **Pasty**
>
> "This is authentic Cornish pasty with traditional filling of beef and potato."
>
> It can be found in chests, trap rooms or regular rooms.
>
> **Mystery meat**
>
> "Eat at your own risk!"
>
> Mystery meat is dropped by crabs. Eating mystery meat is dangerous, because it might have the following negative effects: Poisoned, Burning, Stuffed, Bind. Mystery meat could also be harmless, but the chance is slight. The only way to make mystery meat safe is to cook it. If the player is starving, mystery meat will not completely sate the player, like other types of food, but instead will return the player to the hungry state. Always eat mystery meat over water, this way you will only be damadged slightly if you catch fire becuase of the mystery meat.
>
> **Overpriced ration of food**
>
> "It looks exactly like a standard ration of food but smaller"
>
> Overpriced ration of food can be bought from a shop on level 6, 11 or 16. Similar to mystery meat and chargrilled meat the overpriced ration of food will not completely sate the player, if the player is starving. As the amount is much smaller it will also keep hunger at by for a shorter amount of time.
>
> **Chargrilled meat**
>
> "It looks like a decent steak."
>
> The player can get chargrilled meat by dropping mystery meat on a grass area and then setting the area on fire. By cooking the mystery meat all its negative effects will disappear. Similar to mystery meat and overpriced ration of food the chargrilled meat will not completely sate the player, if the player is straving.

Downloaded and played the game. That's pretty much it...

Answer (score 1):

There is now also "Frozen carpaccio" attainable by mixing mystery meat with ice - either an ice trap or by throwing a potion of frost at it.

Answer (score 0):

More about Chargrilled meat:

You can obtain it by throwing a Mystery Meat on any tile in flame, such grass and doors.
You can throw two or three Mystery Meats on a burning door.
Also a fire trap will cook Mystery Meat. It could be randomly cooked if in your inventory while burning!

Anyway, try to farm Healing potions from Swarm and you can survive ages without food.