# What can I do if I'm starving and I have no food?

Tags: pixel-dungeon

I'm not sure how am I supposed to handle food in Pixel Dungeon: apparently you find it at random, and if you don't happen to find it, you'll just starve to death. Is that normal behaviour, or I'm missing something?

Everything else, AFAIK, is just matter of strategy+tactics, luck helps but you can manage to go on anyway... but with food, not quite.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119249/is-there-anything-to-eat-besides-basic-rations

Comment: Just an addition you can teleport Piranhas with a wand and mystery meat will turn up where they teleported so long as it is on dry land.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can advise you not to eat when hungry, but when only starving. Even then, starvation only starts to drain life after a while. And healing potion is the most commonly found potion in the game, which helps sustaining hunger a lot easier.
There is a piece of food on every floor. Explore each floor until you've found it.

- Being a warrior would make your life easier since they gain 5hp when they eat.
- Being a rogue is fool-proof since being one makes your hunger drain slower.
- Giant Piranhas which are found in flooded vaults always drop a mystery meat when killed.

  - You can kill them safely by holding the door open via throwing an item into the door or burning it
  - A throwing weapon will help you stay alive
- Warlocks gain health and hunger when they kill mobs
- You can sleep to regain health when not in range of any mobs, effectively exchanging health in expense of hunger; then use that health gained to survive more ticks of starvation.

Comment: You can also get mystery meat from crabs but it is a lower percentage chance.

Comment: But when you encounter a crab, there is (almost) no escape; therefore it cannot be counted as a choice in my opinion.

Comment: No but they are still a source of food, though not reliable they should not be discounted, as crabs are also easier to kill than the piranhas. I gained 3 mystery meats from crabs on a single level which was incredibly handy for that particular game.

Comment: I'm not saying that is not right, but it would be too obvious to say 'kill all the crabs' which every player considers at some point instead of saying something like 'there is a way to kill piranhas' which almost all of the new players tried and swore to never try again.

Comment: Also dew drops and the dew drop jar are a good way to act as a preventative, like you stated with healing potions :)

Answer (score 2):

You can throw mystery meat onto fire traps or shoot it with a fire wand to cook it and make it safe to eat, that can help you last a bit longer. You can also hold off until you're hungry or starving before using one of those healing wells as they will restore your health as well as your hunger.

Answer (score 1):

There is a piece of food on every level (sometimes even more), as well as some of the creatures will drop edible things rarely, the best course I have found is to stick to level three till you have several pieces of food from the crabs there.